# nginx map request post with files to a django upstream server

Tags: django, nginx

I have three upstream gunicorn servers with nginx sitting in front of them what I want to do now is to map all request post with files to a particular server and every other one to the group of upstream servers so that one of the servers is dedicated to file upload and processing .I'll appreciate if this can be done with two sets of upstream servers .

what I currently have.

```
upstream appservers {
    server http://192.168.1.1:8000;
    server http://192.168.1.2:8000;
    server http://192.168.1.3:8000;
    }
```

What I want to do is

```
upstream appservers {
    server http://192.168.1.1:8000;
    server http://192.168.1.2:8000;
    }

upstream file_processors {
    server http://192.168.1.3:8000;
    server http://192.168.1.4:8000;
    }

server {
    location / {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass  http://file_processors;
            break;
        }
        proxy_pass http://appservers;
        }
```